# If $M_n$ is a a martingale, how to prove the following properties?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

[image]

Another confusion: from the definition, if $M_n$ is a martingale $~E(M_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n)=M_n~$ could it implies $~E(M_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_k)=M_k~,~~ k\le n~$.

Comment: For your "Another confusion" comment:  Can you simplify $$E\bigg(E(X|\mathscr{F}_{k+1})\bigg|\mathscr{F}_{k}\bigg)?$$
If you know how to do that, try inducting on $n-k$ to evaluate $E(M_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_k)$

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me how to simplify it? and Mk and Mn are independent or not?